# Entity Framework Core: model is populated incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF Core, and using this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=visual-studio) I've got an unexpected result, namely, the data looks normal in the model when it's just populated, but in a new instance of the context, the navigation property in the principal entity is not populated, and the navigation property in the dependent entity is populated in a peculiar way.

Here is the model (the code from the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=visual-studio) is slightly modified):

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EFGetStarted
{
    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlite("Data Source=blogging.db");
        }
    }

    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return
                "{" +
                "BlogId: " + BlogId + ", " +
                "Name: " + Name + ", " +
                "Posts.Count: " + Posts.Count +
                "}";
        }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return
                "{" + 
                "PostId: " + PostId + ", " +
                "Content: " + Content + ", " +
                "BlogId: " + BlogId + 
                "}";
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the program:

```cs
using static System.Console;

namespace EFGetStarted
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            CreateContents(new BloggingContext());
            Print(new BloggingContext());
        }

        static void CreateContents(BloggingContext db)
        {
            AddBlog(db);
            Print(db);
        }

        private static void AddBlog(BloggingContext db)
        {
            var blog = new Blog { Name = "Blog 1" };
            db.Add(blog);

            blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Content = "Post 1" });
            blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Content = "Post 2" });
            blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Content = "Post 3" });

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        private static void Print(BloggingContext db)
        {
            PrintBlogs(db);
            PrintPosts(db);
        }

        private static void PrintBlogs(BloggingContext db)
        {
            WriteLine("---- Blogs: ----");
            foreach (var blog in db.Blogs) Print(blog);
            WriteLine("");
        }

        private static void PrintPosts(BloggingContext db)
        {
            WriteLine("---- Posts: ----");
            foreach (var post in db.Posts) Print(post);
            WriteLine("");
        }

        private static void Print(Blog blog)
        {
            WriteLine(blog);
            foreach (var post in blog.Posts) WriteLine(post);
            WriteLine();
        }

        private static void Print(Post post)
        {
            WriteLine(post);
            WriteLine(post.Blog);
            foreach (var blogPost in post.Blog.Posts) WriteLine(blogPost);
            WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The program produces the following output:

```json
---- Blogs: ----
{BlogId: 1, Name: 'Blog 1', Posts.Count: 3}
{PostId: 1, Content: 'Post 1', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: 'Post 2', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 3, Content: 'Post 3', BlogId: 1}


---- Posts: ----
{PostId: 1, Content: 'Post 1', BlogId: 1}
{BlogId: 1, Name: 'Blog 1', Posts.Count: 3}
{PostId: 1, Content: 'Post 1', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: 'Post 2', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 3, Content: 'Post 3', BlogId: 1}

{PostId: 2, Content: 'Post 2', BlogId: 1}
{BlogId: 1, Name: 'Blog 1', Posts.Count: 3}
{PostId: 1, Content: 'Post 1', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: 'Post 2', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 3, Content: 'Post 3', BlogId: 1}

{PostId: 3, Content: 'Post 3', BlogId: 1}
{BlogId: 1, Name: 'Blog 1', Posts.Count: 3}
{PostId: 1, Content: 'Post 1', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: 'Post 2', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 3, Content: 'Post 3', BlogId: 1}


---- Blogs: ----
{BlogId: 1, Name: 'Blog 1', Posts.Count: 0}


---- Posts: ----
{PostId: 1, Content: 'Post 1', BlogId: 1}
{BlogId: 1, Name: 'Blog 1', Posts.Count: 1}
{PostId: 1, Content: 'Post 1', BlogId: 1}

{PostId: 2, Content: 'Post 2', BlogId: 1}
{BlogId: 1, Name: 'Blog 1', Posts.Count: 2}
{PostId: 1, Content: 'Post 1', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: 'Post 2', BlogId: 1}

{PostId: 3, Content: 'Post 3', BlogId: 1}
{BlogId: 1, Name: 'Blog 1', Posts.Count: 3}
{PostId: 1, Content: 'Post 1', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: 'Post 2', BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 3, Content: 'Post 3', BlogId: 1}
```

As you can see, when the model is created, the blog has three posts, and every post references the blog with the same three posts.

When printed using a new instance of the context, the blog has zero posts and, looks like, posts reference different instances of the blog each with a different number of associated posts.

How to make the model in the new instance of the context look like the one in which it was populated?

Comment: What do you mean for `When printed in a new connection`?

Comment: Maybe it was incorrect, but by "new connection" I meant "new context instance". I assumed that when a context instance is created it creates a new connection to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the code. Code doesn't have include statement, this is why you can't see posts. Try this:

```
private static void PrintBlogs(BloggingContext db)
        {
          
            var blogs = db.Blogs.Include(i => i.Posts).ToArray();

            WriteLine("---- Blogs: ----");
            foreach (var blog in blogs) Print(blog);
            WriteLine("");
        }

        private static void PrintPosts(BloggingContext db)
        {
            var posts = db.Posts.Include(i => i.Blog).ToArray();

            WriteLine("---- Posts: ----");
            foreach (var post in posts) Print(post);
            WriteLine("");
        }
```

Now the  result is:

```
---- Blogs: ----
{BlogId: 1, Name: Blog 1, Posts.Count: 3}
{PostId: 1, Content: Post 1, BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: Post 2, BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 3, Content: Post 3, BlogId: 1}


---- Posts: ----
{PostId: 1, Content: Post 1, BlogId: 1}
{BlogId: 1, Name: Blog 1, Posts.Count: 3}
{PostId: 1, Content: Post 1, BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: Post 2, BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 3, Content: Post 3, BlogId: 1}

{PostId: 2, Content: Post 2, BlogId: 1}
{BlogId: 1, Name: Blog 1, Posts.Count: 3}
{PostId: 1, Content: Post 1, BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: Post 2, BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 3, Content: Post 3, BlogId: 1}

{PostId: 3, Content: Post 3, BlogId: 1}
{BlogId: 1, Name: Blog 1, Posts.Count: 3}
{PostId: 1, Content: Post 1, BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 2, Content: Post 2, BlogId: 1}
{PostId: 3, Content: Post 3, BlogId: 1}
```

Comment: Sergey, thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it! I did not try to make this code simple, it's how it was in the tutorial, I just removed a couple of fields that did make any difference.

I tried your solution but got some compilation errors related to the InverseProperty attributes. I fixed the errors, here is the code that I was able to compile and generate the migration for:

```

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in my answer. I did'n blame you to make it  simple, I was going to mention Microsoft.  And I fixed another typo. Instead of "Post.Blog"  I typed "Blog.Post". Now it is fixed. You can check again. Everything should be working properly.

Comment: Here is the code that I was able to compile and generate a migration for:
```
   public partial class Blog
   {
        ...
        [InverseProperty("Blog")]
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        ...
    }

    public class Post
    {
        ...
        [InverseProperty("Posts")]
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
        ...
    }
````
But, as I mentioned it worked exactly the same.

Comment: In your class Post  I don't see  [ForeignKey(nameof(BlogId))] it is very important. it will not work properly without this.

Comment: The length of a comment is limited, so I omitted the parts that are exactly the same as in your code, including the part you mentioned above.

Comment: @user1174703 -  I was really interested why it was not printed properly. So I created db and tested. I found   a bug. See my updated answer. Now everything is printing ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227944/discussion-between-user1174703-and-sergey).